# CodeIgniter User is able to copy and paste URL and access main page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables

I am trying to build a simple login system using CodeIgniter. I have placed all of my functions into one controller and I have also placed a session check function called is_logged_in into the controller. However, the user can still copy and paste the URL once they have logged out and view the main page. It seems like my is logged in function isn't working. Am I missing something? It only works if I place a check in my header every time instead. Here is my code.

Controller file

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
}

function checklogin()
{
    $this->load->model('user');
    $query = $this->user->validate_login();

    if($query)
    {
        redirect('portal/home');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }

}

function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('is_logged_in');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect($this->index(),'refresh');
}

function is_logged_in()
{

    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    if(!isset($is_logged_in)||$is_logged_in!=TRUE)
    {
        $this->index();
    }
}

function home()
{
    $this->is_logged_in();
    $data['main_content'] = 'home';
    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
}

function statements()
{
    $this->is_logged_in();
    $data['main_content'] = 'statements';
    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
}

function about()
{
    $this->is_logged_in();
    $data['main_content'] = 'about';
    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
}



}
?>
```

This is what I place into my headers that actually works instead of the function

```
<?php
if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
{
    redirect('portal/index');
}
?>
```

User Model

```
<?php
```

class User extends CI_Model{

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function validate_login()
{
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
    $password = $this->security->xss_clean(md5($this->input->post('password')));

    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);

    $query = $this->db->get('accounts');

    if($query->num_rows()==1)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $sess_data = array(
            'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in'=>TRUE,
            'privilege'=>$row->privilege
            );
        }

        $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
    //  echo $password;
    }
}

}

?>
```

Also, how can I combine the commented out part in the user model with the next lines? I want an error message to be sent if no input is placed. Hope I can get help with this.

Comment: add `$this->load->library('session');`, `$this->load->helper('form');` `$this->load->library('form_validation');` in your controller

Comment: But I've autoloaded it already? form and URL in the helper, session and form validation in the library section of the autoload file.

Comment: I'm trying to edit the functions but nothing seems to be working for some reason

Comment: You are not using the function is_logged_in() in the controller

Comment: Huh? But I'm calling it in every function? Under function home() there is a is_logged_in called. Unless thats the wrong way of doing it? Sorry, I'm new to CI so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Sorry. I did not see it hahahaa

Comment: Is there a way to solve this? Haha. Not sure if placing the code in the html header is the best way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So much wrong in this. Do not, not ever, use a single controller for your application. Things will get pretty big, pretty fast, and then you have one unreadable blob of a file. Keep your application code normalized. That's why you are using MVC. If you then need a method accessible from every, or nearly every controller, then put this function into a base controller(MY_Controller i.e.), or a model, or a library, depending on the functionality of this method. But in your case, this is for a base controller. This wont help with your problem, but just a friendly suggestion.

The problem with your code is, the visitor hits the URL for method "statements" and this is what happens:

1. statements calls is_logged_in
2. is_logged_in determines user is not logged in and calls index
3. index loads the login view
4. statements method loads the statements view

After you check for log in, and determine that the user is not logged in, you have to prevent further execution of other parts of your code. I would suggest having is_logged_in method returning a bool(false) value, and the statements(and other methods) then stopping execution. But if you would separate your code like you should over multiple controllers, then maybe have the is_logged_in controller to redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: Noted. Will separate them. Thanks!

Comment: Oh how can I set form validation rules and get the post replies at the same time?